# How to track SLA of VM availability set (or availability zone) through heartbeats with Log Analytics (KQL)

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-resource-graph, azure-monitor

I want to track the SLAs of our VMs in a Monitor Workbook using a Log Analytics query.
For this, I use the 'Heartbeat' table, which gives the heartbeats of each VM.
However, some of our VMs are in an availability set/zone and as such, the SLA is only broken,
if in an interval of 1 minute, both heartbeats are missing.
As such I need to be able to group the heartbeats by availability set/zone in the query, but there doesn't seem to be such a property on the heartbeat.

I can use a separate Azure Resource Graph query to search for which VMs are in an availability set/zone, but when I merge this query with my Log Analytics query, I can't do any further Kusto Query Language processing on the query (I can only merge the tables).

For information, these are my Log Analytics Heartbeat query and my Resource Graph SLA query:

```
let timeRangeStart = {TimeRange:start};
let timeRangeEnd = {TimeRange:end};
Heartbeat
| where ResourceType == "virtualMachines"
| extend ResourceGroup = case(ResourceGroup <> "", ResourceGroup, "On-Prem")
| where TimeGenerated > timeRangeStart and TimeGenerated < timeRangeEnd and Computer in ({Servers})
| extend Resource=tolower(iff(isempty(_ResourceId), Resource, _ResourceId))
| summarize heartbeat_tot = count() by Resource,ResourceGroup, SubscriptionId
| extend total_number_of_buckets=round((timeRangeEnd-timeRangeStart)/1m)
| extend round(availability_rate=heartbeat_tot*100/total_number_of_buckets,2)
| extend availability_rate = min_of(availability_rate, 100)
| order by availability_rate asc
```

```
Resources // VMs
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| extend AvSet = properties.availabilitySet.id
| extend AvZone = properties.availabilityZone.id
| extend VMname_SLA = iff(isnotempty(AvZone), AvZone, iff(isnotempty(AvSet), AvSet, id))
| extend SLA_VM = iff(isnotnull(AvZone), '99.99%', iff(isnotnull(AvSet), '99.95%', ''))
| extend managedBy = tolower(id)
| join kind = leftouter (
Resources // Disks
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/disks'
| where isnotempty(managedBy)
| extend managedBy = tolower(managedBy)
// What do Standard HDD disks have as SKU tag??? I used StandardHDD for the time being
| extend Tier_disk = sku.tier
| extend SLA_disk = iff(Tier_disk == 'StandardHDD', '95%', iff(Tier_disk == 'Standard', '99.5%', '99.9%'))
) on managedBy
| extend SLA_tot = iff(isnotempty(SLA_VM), SLA_VM, SLA_disk)
| project managedBy, VMname_SLA, SLA_tot
| order by managedBy asc
```

Answer (score 0):

How many resources is it?

If it is not a large number of resources, a workaround would be:

1. run your ARG query in text parameter, and format the results of the query to effectively generate a json array of objects, with id, location, etc that you need.  then mark this parameter as hidden
2. in your Logs query, reference that parameter json text before the query, and use KQL operators to turn that JSON structure into a table.  then you can join/filter on that table in the query

it isn't optimal, and won't work *well* if there are large numbers of resources since every time you run your query you're effectively "uploading" a json blob and then immediately parsing it apart again.

Comment: The solution is supposed to work for any number of resources, which can be a large amount. As such, your solution is indeed viable within the constraints I originally posted, though not so usefull in practice.
The workaround I have used now is to let a function app write my ARG data to a Log Analytics table daily. That way I can combine Log Analytics tables in 1 query.

Comment: this is a good way to build a "cache" table like that.  you should post it as its own answer for how you solved your problem.  (if you can add concrete details how you did it, i'm sure others would find it useful)